# Angular service is not returning error response

Tags: angularjs

I am calling service `saveRouteInfo()`, but only success callback is getting invoked for both error and success in the controller.

Service

```
gisApp.factory('rpServc', function($http) {
      return {
          saveRouteInfo:function(routeInfo){
              return $http.post("/GISWebApp/gis/api/v1/route",routeInfo).then(
                  function(response) 
                  {  
                      return response.data;           
                  }, function(response) {
                      return response.data;
                  });   
            },
      }; 
});
```

controller

```
rpServc.saveRouteInfo(routeInfo).then(function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));

}, function(error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0trpgxm8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use $q

```
 gisApp.factory('rpServc', function($http, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        return {
            saveRouteInfo:function(routeInfo){
                return $http.post("/GISWebApp/gis/api/v1/route", routeInfo).
                then(function(response) {
                  return response;          
                }, function(reason) {
                  return $q.reject(reason);
                });
            },
        };
    });
```

Comment: success is deprecated since v1.5 in angularjs. Please avoid using it.

Comment: Updated answer by deleting success

Answer (score 0):

you should read the  [$q angular promises documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

and return either resolved or rejected promise so you can catch the rejected ones in the .then() second function.